# How do I locate makemytrip.com 'From City' input field in Selenium?

Tags: selenium

Below is the html details for the field:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="react-autowhatever-1" aria-expanded="true" class="react-autosuggest__input react-autosuggest__input--open" placeholder="From" value="">
```

Tried below for the same field but not working:

```
//div[@class='fsw_inputBox searchCity inactiveWidget activeWidget']/div/div/div/div/input
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
//input[@id='fromCity']
```

Just a suggestion, please try to avoid using indexes in your xpaths as much as possible. With indexes, in case if there is one more element added in the DOM(may be because of change in design or for some new feature addition) the xpaths may no more remain valid and will result in your script failure.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with CSS selector

`input[placeholder="From"]`

Above selector will give you only one result.